# Kivy Install gone awry - Windows 10 (was working, now not after gstreamer)

Tags: python, kivy

Tried installing Kivy in Windows 10. Install the basics using

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew  --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/packages/simple
python -m pip install kivy
```

It worked for one test "Hello World. I then tried installing gstreamer and then started getting errors.

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Ben\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-01-11_7.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL          ] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider at all!
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ImportError: No module named PIL
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
```

Tried to find PIL and used  python -m pip install image

```
python -m pip install image
```

Now when I run my main.py I get the black box of a Kivy window, nothing inside, and a new error

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Ben\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-01-11_11.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <4.5.0 NVIDIA 358.91>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <NVIDIA Corporation>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <GeForce GTX 780/PCIe/SSE2>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Shading version <4.50 NVIDIA>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO              ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO              ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
 Exception Exception: Exception('tostring() has been removed. Please call tobytes() instead.',) in 'kivy.graphics.instructions.Ren
derContext.set_texture' ignored
```

Can't help but feel I bricked my install and no idea how to start from scratch. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ended up with a full uninstall if Kivy and its dependencies.

```
python -m pip uninstall kivy

python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.sdl2

python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.glew

python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.gstreamer

python -m pip uninstall image
```

Since the problem came after gstreamer, I avoided again on reinstall

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools

python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew \
 --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/packages/simple/

python -m pip install kivy
```

After that was able to run things as normal (for now :D )

I hope this helps someone out there with Kivy issues on Windows 10