# Cannot display anything but a solid-color window with Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

**My problem**

I'm trying to use Kivy 1.10.1 in Python 3.7 on Windows 10, but when I run any of the example programs that come with Kivy (e.g. the [pong](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html) and ["Hello world"](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html#create-an-application) examples), they always display only a window containing nothing but a solid color, usually black. Otherwise, they seem to work: No errors appear, the title bar buttons work, mouse-click positions can be printed in the Python shell, etc.

**What I've ruled out**

A similar problem with running Kivy on Ubuntu has received a very short but accepted answer on [Ask Ubunto](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761161/kivy-hello-world-script-yields-black-screen-on-ubuntu-14-04). The OP's problem there was fixed by installing ffmpeg, but I did that, and it didn't fix my problem.

Another similar problem with running Kivy on Windows 10 was solved on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731922/kivy-install-gone-awry-windows-10-was-working-now-not-after-gstreamer) by uninstalling Kivy and its dependencies then reinstalling everything but gstreamer. I did that too, and it didn't fix my problem.

Also without fixing the problem, I've installed Kivy on Python 3.6.6 as well as 3.7.0 both 32-bit and 64-bit.

I also tried setting KIVY_GL_BACKEND in system environment variables to each of the possible values listed on Kivy's [website](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.cgl.html#module-kivy.graphics.cgl) and all of them but angle_sdl2 failed (raised a "Kivy Fatal Error" saying "Minimum required OpenGL version (2.0) NOT found!" even though a higher version was available).

In response to a comment below, I submitted this [question](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5931) to Kivy's issue tracker where the question was closed without a solution except for the general suggestion that I may need to update my graphics drivers. So I tried that too, and it didn't fix my problem.

In response to another comment below, I manually resized the window, but that didn't fix my problem either.

**An example of the problem**

Here is an official "Hello world" example module I've run.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Here is the (error-free) log it yields:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Victor\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-08-31_1.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Activate GLES2/ANGLE context
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <angle_sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b"OpenGL ES 2.0 (ANGLE 2.1.0.b'')">
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Google Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'ANGLE (Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 Direct3D11 vs_4_1 ps_4_1)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b"OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00 (ANGLE 2.1.0.b'')">
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

Here is the window it displays.

[image: a solid-black window with a normal title bar]

Comment: that smells like a bug, report it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I see Kivy's website links to an [issues page](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues) where bugs can be reported. I'll try it.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem on macOS with kivy 1.10.1 using python 3.7

Comment: Found this issue: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5987 -- resize the window manually and widgets appear

Comment: @Doug Currie, as I just updated in my question, manually resizing the window didn't make any widgets appear for me. Thanks for the suggestion and link though.